# What is the maximum size of a Column Value that MySQL / phpmyadmin can show?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have the a column value which is very huge, and I'm unable to check if it even right. I get the following note in phpmyadmin :

```
Because of its length,this column might not be editable.
```

How do I have a look at this complete value AND what is the maximum size that a column of type "TEXT" can hold? Do I have to change the type of column? If so, what should it be.

Thank you,
JJ

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: Have you tried to print it?

Comment: @Mark As per that document, LONGTEXT stores the largest values right?

Comment: @DavidWilkins I didn't print it but indirectly check if the whole data for there through my code and unfortunately it wasn't there. I was guessing the data wasn't complete

Comment: @Mark I've updated it to LONGTEXT and the data seems to be complete :) Thank you for the reference, I hope this is the solution.If not, can suggest something better?

Comment: If you are overflowing a LONGTEXT, you might want to re-architect your application